# SyntaxError: App.js: Unexpected token (25:0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm newbie in React-Native facing issue while working on existing app. I'm struck in this error. It's an old project may be changes in code structure that's why i'm getting this error.

`SyntaxError: /Users/xtremehardware/Projects/whoopauserapp/App.js: Unexpected token (25:0)`

This is App.js file

```js
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, Image, Platform, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {Spinner} from './src/components';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from "./src/store";
import AppRouter from "./src/router";
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';

import { Sentry } from '@sentry_react-native';

const sentryDsn = Platform.select({"ios":"https://ccbf3ee4e5ff4b09a10ba6acc28acf56:359b7f587a65432f9c22aa96b23d8660@sentry.io/263386","android":"https://ccbf3ee4e5ff4b09a10ba6acc28acf56:359b7f587a65432f9c22aa96b23d8660@sentry.io/263386"});
Sentry.config(sentryDsn).install();

let {store, persistor} = configureStore();

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();
  }

splashScreen() {
    return (
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image source={require('./src/assets/images/splash_screen.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage}/>
        </View>
        <Spinner/>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={this.splashScreen()}>
        <Provider store={store} style={styles.container}>
          <AppRouter/>
        </Provider>
      </PersistGate>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    width: null,
    height: null,
  },

});
```

`View` Getting error on this first line after return in splash screen.

Comment: Where is the opening of Fragment element?

Comment: I've added `<Fragment>` now getting error on `<Fragment>`

Comment: Guess: the file should be called .jsx so it gets compiled correctly?

Comment: can you should what your styles.imageContainer looks like?

Comment: Try backticks in your return like: `return (\`<View>...</View>\`);`

Comment: @admcfajn https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: I've updated my code kindly se..

Comment: I copy/pasted this code into a codesandbox and formatted. Other than fixing the indentation the only diff I noticed was double quoted path for the image source, `"./src/assets/images/splash_screen.png"`. I don't see any errors (other than what I can't import, because react-native).

Comment: I repeat: this code is probably being processed by Webpack or similar, right? For that to work, the file ending must probably be `.jsx`, otherwise it's not getting pre-processed as JSX…!?

Comment: @deceze Depends on configuration I suppose. *.js is perfectly valid for writing react components. In my experience using *.jsx only really makes the IDE display a react file icon versus a generic js icon in the project file explorer. Easy to identify your react files from regular js files at a glance if you have a poor naming convention.

Comment: @Drew Yeah, it depends on the configuration, but *something* is apparently trying to interpret a JSX file as plain JS here, so that's a possibility to look into…

Comment: @DrewReese i'm not getting error `"./src/assets/images/splash_screen.png"` here i'm getting error on starting tag of `<View>` i've created new project with expo it runs smoothly without any error not even on `<View>`.

Comment: @deceze this is base App.js file i can't change it to any other than .js. It's running fine on newly created project but throws an error on this.

Comment: @deceze true, but how often have you seen a suggestion like that actually work? :) ( OP only has the one return function posted at the time of comment, so i figured a wild-guess was better than none )